# How to use DbContextFactory with repository pattern in Blazor server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app and I'm setting up the db context factory:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<AppContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("App"));
});
```

I also use repository pattern, for example currently it is as follows:

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(AppContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }
}
```

I also have services that get a number of repositories through DI and these repositories must be within a "unit of work".

How can I set up the repositories to receive the same instance of the db context? Can I use repository pattern with `DBContextFactory` or do I need to create the repositories with `new`?

Answer (score 0):

There's a school amongst the developer community who believe that implementing a full stack *Repository* and *Unit of Work* pattern over Entity Framework is an anti-pattern.

Why?  Because Entity Framework itself already implements those patterns.  A `DbSet<T>` is a repository and a `DbContext` is a Unit of Work.

Consider saving an invoice and invoice items.  You need some form of Aggregate entity.  How do you do an all or nothing save where you have an `Invoice` Repository and an `InvoiceItem` Repository?  Construct yet another layer to handle the it?

There's a more simplistic approach shown below.

The method is the *Unit of Work* and the `dbContext` is scoped to the lifetime of the method.  The updates are applied to the `DbSet` repositories.  The `dbContext` [the unit of work] get's disposed [and destroyed] when the method goes out of scope, but the underlying `DbConnection` is recycled by the factory.

```cs
public CommandResult AddInvoice(InvoiceAggregate aggregate)
{
    using var dbContext =_factory.CreateDbContext();

    // creates a Dbo object from the domain object and saves it to EF
    var dboRoot = _invoiceMap.Map(aggregate.root);
    dbContext.Add<DboInvoice>(dboRoot);

    // loop through the Invoice items and save each one  to EF
    foreach (var item in aggregate.Items)
    {
        var dboItem = _invoiceItemMap.Map(item);
        dbContext.Add<DboInvoiceItem>(dboItem);
    }

    try
    {
        // Commit all changes as a single transaction
        var transactions = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CommandResult.Success();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        var message = $"Your Fail Message";
        _logger.LogError(message);
        return CommandResult.Failure(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var message = $"Your Fail Message";
        _logger.LogError(message);
        return CommandResult.Failure(message);
    }
}
```

In reality you need to track state in an aggregate: you may have items marked for deletion, edited or added, so the command (Create/Update/Delete) handler will be much more complex.

Here's a real world *CQS* command handler of mine for the Invoice example:

```cs
/// ============================================================
/// Author: Shaun Curtis, Cold Elm Coders
/// License: Use And Donate
/// If you use it, donate something to a charity somewhere
/// ============================================================

namespace Blazr.App.Infrastructure;

public sealed class InvoiceAggregateCommandHandler<TDbContext>
    : ICommandHandler<InvoiceAggregate>
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> _factory;
    private readonly ILogger<InvoiceAggregateCommandHandler<TDbContext>> _logger;
    private readonly IDboEntityMap<DboInvoice, Invoice> _invoiceMap;
    private readonly IDboEntityMap<DboInvoiceItem, InvoiceItem> _invoiceItemMap;

    public InvoiceAggregateCommandHandler(IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> factory, ILogger<InvoiceAggregateCommandHandler<TDbContext>> logger, IDboEntityMap<DboInvoice, Invoice> invoiceMap, IDboEntityMap<DboInvoiceItem, InvoiceItem> invoiceItemMap)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _logger = logger;
        _invoiceMap = invoiceMap;
        _invoiceItemMap = invoiceItemMap;
    }

    public async ValueTask<CommandResult> ExecuteAsync(CommandRequest<InvoiceAggregate> request)
    {
        using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();

        var aggregate = request.Item;
        var root = aggregate.Root;
        var dboRoot = _invoiceMap.Map(root);

        // Create the aggregate if it's marked as new
        if (root.EntityState.IsNew)
            dbContext.Add<DboInvoice>(dboRoot);

        // Delete the aggregate if it is marked as deleted)
        else if (root.EntityState.MarkedForDeletion)
            dbContext.Remove<DboInvoice>(dboRoot);

        // Update the aggregate if it is marked as modified)
        else if (aggregate.IsRootDirty)
            dbContext.Update<DboInvoice>(dboRoot);

        // Update all the existing items based on their state
        foreach (var item in aggregate.AllItems)
        {
            var dboItem = _invoiceItemMap.Map(item);

            if (item.EntityState.IsNew)
                dbContext.Add<DboInvoiceItem>(dboItem);

            else if (item.EntityState.MarkedForDeletion)
                dbContext.Remove<DboInvoiceItem>(dboItem);

            else if (item.EntityState.IsMutated)
                dbContext.Update<DboInvoiceItem>(dboItem);
        }

        try
        {
            // Commit all changes as a single transaction
            var transactions = await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CommandResult.Success();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            var message = $"Failed to save the Invoice aggregate {request.Item.Uid}.  Transaction aborted";
            _logger.LogError(message);
            return CommandResult.Failure(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var message = $"An error occured trying to save the Invoice aggregate {request.Item.Uid}.  Detail: {e.Message}.";
            _logger.LogError(message);
            return CommandResult.Failure(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the meat of this answer is in `using var dbContext = _factory.CreateDbContext();`.  The UoW is the method.

Comment: @HH -  Important point - I've added more commentary to explain that in the answer.

Comment: OK one more nitpick: it really gets to be Disposed, by the `using` declaration. The only thing that is recycled afaik is the DbConnection, by the connection pool. You don't want to recycle the DbContext, and esp. not its ChangeTracker.