Scoped service instances in Blazor
I am new to Blazor. I'm creating a simple object to get familiar with it. Using Entity Framework with SQL Server as back end.
I created a customer class that has orders in it. Created a ICustomerService, IOrderService to perform CRUD operations on these entities which have access to the DbContext to access/update/add items to the database.
I've registered these services as scoped:
services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();

Customer object is like this:
public class Customer
{
    ICollection<Order> Orders = { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}

Customer details component displays list of orders and has a button when clicked on it takes them to Order details page. Or clicking on ordered takes them to details page.
Order object is created as
Order = OrderService.GetOrder(orderId); 

OrderService is injected here.
Order object is bound to an EditForm.
The user updates some fields of the order in the component/page and instead of saving navigates to customer details page where in order list -> corresponding order shows the updated values which shouldn’t as the user is navigated away from the order details page without saving.
I understand this behavior is due to scoped instance as it is retaining the changes in memory.
How to fix this so orders in customer details page displays the values that are in the database not in memory?

This is a known problem: Blazor does not offer usable Scopes. The advice is to use AddDbContextFactory, not AddDbContext. See the docs

Tried adding AddDbContextFactory. When I create the content from this factory in the Razor code behind page on intialized method and used the context to perform operations directly then works fine. But when I make the AddDbContextFactory part of a  IService, registering the service with Scoped causing the same issue of retaining the values in memory. If I change the service to transient works fine. Not sure what the recommended approach?

Read that article, the samples are very short. Use transient services (repositories) and create a dbcontext in a using statement.

Use Unit of Work DbContexts.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844500/how-to-use-dbcontextfactory-with-repository-pattern-in-blazor-server

Tried creating IDbContextFactory and create an instance of it for each database operation. Now the problem is Customer has two orders saved in the database. User is updating first order and saving using (var _context = factory.CreateDbContext())
{ _context.Customer.Update(customer); _context.SaveChanges()} This not saving Orders and throwing an exception expected to update 1 row but 0 rows. This due to detached entities in the context. How to solve this?

In MVC, scope lifetime is one "http request-response". But for blazor is whole circuit(as long as the websocket connected). So the instance is. You could use transient or try clear the tracked changes before "_dbContext.SaveChanges" happen.
public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public MyService(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void ResetDbContext()
    {
        _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();  // Clear tracked entities
    }
}

